# Need helping creating dynamic lower third

Tags: after-effects, after-effects-expressions

I am new to After Effects so I apologize in advance for any misuse of terminology or lack of necessary information. Just let me know if you need anything and I can provide it.

I am trying to create a lower third reveal that I can use in Premiere. I have the lower third made and I used the typewriter preset animation to reveal it. In addition I have a shape that moves along with the animation as an additional reveal element.

I am looking to have this a preset that I can use in Premiere so that when I change the text, the typewriter animation and the shape adjusts according to the length of the text itself.

Here is a reddit link to a post where I ask the same question and it has a video example of what I am trying to accomplish: [Example](https://www.reddit.com/r/AfterEffects/comments/j8s18d/need_help_creating_dynamic_lower_third/)

Please let me know if there's anything else you need from me, thanks.

Comment: What you're looking for are adobe's essential graphics function in premiere. I have never worked with it myself, but it might be a start for googling away.